# Cómo obtener el id de <td> en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-tabla

Estuve tratando de obtener el id de mi td con el método usual:

`document.getElementById()`

Pero el problema es que los ID de mi tabla son dinámicos y no sé cómo obtenerlos usando JavaScript.

Esta es mi tabla:

```
             @foreach (var p in Model)
              {
                    <tr class="datos">
                        <td class="modulo" style="text-align: center" id="@p.Parametros.Modulos.Id">@p.Parametros.Modulos.Nombre</td>

                        <td class="params" id="@p.ParametroId" style="text-align: center">@p.Parametros.Nemonico</td>

                        <td class="canal" id="@p.CanalId" style="text-align: center">@p.Canales.Nombre</td>

                        <td class="valor" name="ValorDefault" id="@p.ParametroId @p.CanalId" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true"></td>

                        <td><button type="button" name="boton" id="@p.CanalId @p.ParametroId" value="@p.ValorDefault" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false" onclick="AgregarValor('@p.ValorDefault', @p.ParametroId, @p.CanalId)">Default</button></td>
                    </tr>
                 }
```

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let mods = $('#valoresParametros').val().split(";");

            if (mods) {
                for (let i = 0; i < mods.length; i++) {
                    let vals = mods[i].split(',');
 
                    $('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function () {
                        if (document.getElementById()) //Acá quiero recuperar el ID del primer td

                    }.bind(this));
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: debes recorrer un for con la misma catidad de veces que hubiese recorrido el foreach, en tu html debes concatenar la posicion  del foreach  no el o usar miFila.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

Answer (score 1):

Realiza estos cambios en tu javascript.

Donde pone esto:

```javascript
$('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function () {
    if (document.getElementById()) //Acá quiero recuperar el ID del primer td
}.bind(this));
```

pon esto:

```javascript
$('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function(index, tr) {
    $(tr).children('td').each(function() {
        console.log(this.id)
    });
}.bind(this));
```

**Explicación de los cambios:**

1. He agregado los dos parámetros correspondientes al `index` y al `elemento` en la función de la primera línea, tal como indica [su documentación](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) como posible sintaxis de `each()` en jquery.  De este modo podremos referenciar al elemento en sí actual más cómodamente despues.

```javascript
$('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function(index, tr) {
```

2. Recorremos dicho elemento buscando tan solo sus hijos (`children`) y en cada uno de ellos (`each()`) le aplicamos una función, que en este caso será mostrar su `id` por consola referenciándolos mediante `this`:

```javascript
$(tr).children('td').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id)
});
```

Dejo un snippet con datos de muestra parecidos a lo que consigues con tu bucle mostrado en la pregunta:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let mods = $('#valoresParametros').val().split(";");
  if (mods) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mods.length; i++) {
      let vals = mods[i].split(',');
      $('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function(index, tr) {
        $(tr).children('td').each(function() {
          console.log(this.id)
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="valoresParametros" value="modulo:params:canal:valor">
<table id="mytable">
  <tr class="datos">
    <td class="modulo" style="text-align: center" id="Modulos.Id1">Modulos.Nombre1</td>

    <td class="params" id="ParametroId1" style="text-align: center">Nemonico1</td>

    <td class="canal" id="CanalId1" style="text-align: center">Canales.Nombre1</td>

    <td class="valor" name="ValorDefault" id="ParametroId1 CanalId1" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true"></td>

    <td><button type="button" name="boton" id="CanalId1 ParametroId1" value="ValorDefault1" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false" onclick="AgregarValor('ValorDefault1', ParametroId1, CanalId1)">Default</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datos">
    <td class="modulo" style="text-align: center" id="Modulos.Id2">Modulos.Nombre2</td>

    <td class="params" id="ParametroId2" style="text-align: center">Nemonico2</td>

    <td class="canal" id="CanalId2" style="text-align: center">Canales.Nombre2</td>

    <td class="valor" name="ValorDefault" id="ParametroId2 CanalId2" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true"></td>

    <td><button type="button" name="boton" id="CanalId2 ParametroId2" value="ValorDefault2" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false" onclick="AgregarValor('ValorDefault2', ParametroId2, CanalId2)">Default</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datos">
    <td class="modulo" style="text-align: center" id="Modulos.Id3">Modulos.Nombre3</td>

    <td class="params" id="ParametroId3" style="text-align: center">Nemonico3</td>

    <td class="canal" id="CanalId3" style="text-align: center">Canales.Nombre3</td>

    <td class="valor" name="ValorDefault" id="ParametroId3 CanalId3" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true"></td>

    <td><button type="button" name="boton" id="CanalId3 ParametroId3" value="ValorDefault3" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false" onclick="AgregarValor('ValorDefault3', ParametroId3, CanalId3)">Default</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Compadre, se te olvidó explicar los cambios que hiciste y cómo funcionan.

Comment: Para nada, siempre lo hago a posteriori menos cuando es poca cosa o me sale de carrerilla. El tiempo que puedo emplear en explicar lo que he hecho, si finalmente no sirve para el OP, no me lo va a devolver nadie. Por eso pregunto primero si les sirve, por que no seria la primera vez que luego te dicen cosas como "si, bueno, pero lo que yo queria era... " y te cambian la pregunta sobre la marcha.  O bien sale otro con una respuesta mucho más buena la mia y termino eliminandola.  Yo quiero ayudar, pero no quiero perder mi tiempo si no les sirven mis respuestas.

Comment: En este caso concreto, ya tiene una pseudo solucion en los comentarios de la pregunta, y quizás tira por ahi para buscar su solución. Cuando me confirme que efectivamente mi respuesta le sirve o cumple con su pregunta entonces explicaré lo que he hecho con detalle, como siempre hago, pero es facilmente deducible para el ahora mismo porque el snippet le ayuda a entenderlo perfectamente (no para quien viene de nuevo, eso es cierto, y para ellos será la explicación detallada del final, si se da el caso).

Comment: me funcionó! pero no entendi porque usaste el "function (Index, tr)" en el primer each.

Comment: @BilbitBolson acabo de agregar una pequeña explicación en mi respuesta que espero sea suficiente para aclarar tu duda.  Si la respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que el resto de la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente de responder para siempre, gracias.